# quantile regression and high cost of under-predicting

Tags: r, regression, quantile-regression

I have a regression problem where it is better to over-predict than under-predict (i.e. the cost of under-predicting is higher). I think the use of quantile regression with a tau above the median - e.g. 0.75 could be used. Would you agree?

Btw, could various quantile regression models with different taus be combined like an ensemble model to improve predictive performance?

Comment: Would an exact prediction still be preferable to over-prediction? Your proposed solution would be very likely to over-predict.

Comment: exact would be better of course but it is hard as data has high variance - so if an error is made I would rather over than under predict.

Comment: As a first step, I'd define an asymmetric cost function. You can find many examples online: [1](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10471/linear-regression-with-non-symmetric-cost-function), [2](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1540-5915.1974.tb00607.x), [3](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.297.9480&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The latter indeed suggests quantile regression.

Comment: Thanks - yes I came across this ... tbh gradient boosting seems to provide fairly exact predictions at the moment 0 in comparison to ols and quantile regression ...